# How to FIND and MERGE all of the ActiveRecord duplicates in RAILS 4

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am writing an inventory system that imports a datasheet in excel format. there are 3 columns, which is the item_name, colour, price

A lot of the time, the item_name will be the same, however, the colour will be different. I would like to merge all of the colour attribute of records with the same item_name

for example.

```
item_name => "groovy pants", colour => "BLK", price => "$199"
item_name => "groovy pants", colour => "GRY", price => "$199"
item_name => "groovy pants", colour => "RED", price => "$199"
```

I would like to merge the records into a single one

```
item_name => "groovy pants", colour => "BLK,GRY,RED", price => "$199"
```

and delete all of the ones that has been merged.

Thanks!

*********EDIT**********
here is my block taken from the solution provided by Rodrigo.

```
StoreMarkdown.all.each do |markdown|
  duplicated = StoreMarkdown.find_by item_name: markdown.item_name
  puts duplicated

  if duplicated.size > 0
    product.colour = product.colour + ",#{duplicated.map(&:colour).join(',')}"
    product.save!
    duplicated.destroy_all
  end
```

Here is the output for duplicated

```
StoreMarkdown Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "store_markdowns".* FROM "store_markdowns"
  StoreMarkdown Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "store_markdowns".* FROM "store_markdowns" WHERE "store_markdowns"."item_name" = 'Heust Hoodie' LIMIT 1
#<StoreMarkdown:0x007fa2cf93d7c0>
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "store_markdowns".* FROM "store_markdowns" WHERE "store_markdowns"."item_name" = 'Heust Hoodie' LIMIT 1
#<StoreMarkdown:0x007fa2cc211260>
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT "store_markdowns".* FROM "store_markdowns" WHERE "store_markdowns"."item_name" = 'Heust Hoodie' LIMIT 1
#<StoreMarkdown:0x007fa2cda0dc38>
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT "store_markdowns".* FROM "store_markdowns" WHERE "store_markdowns"."item_name" = 'Heust Hoodie' LIMIT 1
#<StoreMarkdown:0x007fa2cda17be8>
  StoreMarkdown Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "store_markdowns".* FROM "store_markdowns" WHERE "store_markdowns"."item_name" = 'Shine Jacket' LIMIT 1
#<StoreMarkdown:0x007fa2cbfac8f8>
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT "store_markdowns".* FROM "store_markdowns" WHERE "store_markdowns"."item_name" = ' Shine Jacket' LIMIT 1
#<StoreMarkdown:0x007fa2cda544d0>
  StoreMarkdown Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "store_markdowns".* FROM "store_markdowns" WHERE "store_markdowns"."item_name" = 'Stres Pant' LIMIT 1
#<StoreMarkdown:0x007fa2cbfc7e78>
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "store_markdowns".* FROM "store_markdowns" WHERE "store_markdowns"."item_name" = 'Stres Pant' LIMIT 1
#<StoreMarkdown:0x007fa2cc249b60>
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "store_markdowns".* FROM "store_markdowns" WHERE "store_markdowns"."item_name" = 'Stres Pant' LIMIT 1
#<StoreMarkdown:0x007fa2cc273e88>
  StoreMarkdown Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "store_markdowns".* FROM "store_markdowns" WHERE "store_markdowns"."item_name" = 'Together Pant' LIMIT 1
#<StoreMarkdown:0x007fa2cf96b3f0>
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT "store_markdowns".* FROM "store_markdowns" WHERE "store_markdowns"."item_name" = 'Together Pant' LIMIT 1
#<StoreMarkdown:0x007fa2d080a0f0>
```

Seems like `duplicated` is going over the item line by line, and duplicated.size is returning undefined method, since `duplicated` is an active record object during the block

Answer (score 0):

This code will do the job:

```
blacklist_ids = []
StoreMarkdown.all.each do |md|
  unless blacklist_ids.include?(md.id)
    blacklist_ids << md.id
    StoreMarkdown.where(item_name: md.item_name,
                        price: md.price).
                  where.not(id: md.id).each do |omd|
      blacklist_ids << omd.id
      new_colours = []
      new_colours << md.colour.split(',')
      new_colours << omd.colour.split(',')
      md.colour = new_colours.uniq.sort.join(',')
      md.save
      omd.destroy
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: there is no associated at all, I might be unclear in my explanation. There is only 1 Model, named StoreMarkdown, and the item_name, colour and price are all attributes of each Markdown items.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you'll use `Product` model too, I would remove the duplicates after importing all products from excel file:

```
Product.all.each do |product|
  duplicated = Product.where(name: product.name)

  if duplicated.size > 0
    product.colors = product.colors + ",#{duplicated.map(&:colors).join(',')}"
    product.save!
    duplicated.destroy_all
  end
end
```

Comment: hmm,, this doesn't seem to work. duplicated.size returned undefined. Upon inspection, duplicated is set to a singular active record object. I have put my version above. I am still pretty newb at Rails, but it seems that this block fetches all product line by line.